# How to implement custom Gibbs sampling scheme in pymc

Tags: pymc

I have a hidden Markov stochastic volatility model (represented as a linear state space model). I am using a hand-written Gibbs sampling scheme to estimate parameters for the model. The actual sampler requires some fairly sophisticated update rules that I believe I need to write by hand. You can see an example of a Julia version of these update rules [here](https://gist.github.com/spencerlyon2/5428ab8d21726acbd22f#file-sampler-jl-L137-L302).

My question is the following: how can I specify the model in a custom way and then hand the job of running the sampler and collecting the samples to pymc? In other words, I am happy to provide code to do all the heavy lifting (how to update each block of parameters on each scan -- utilizing full conditionals within each block), but I want to let pymc handle the "accounting" for me.

I realize that I will probably need to provide more information so that others can answer this question. The problem is I am not sure exactly *what* information will be useful. So, if you feel you can help me out with this, but need more information -- please let me know in a comment and I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of [a custom sampler in PyMC2](http://healthyalgorithms.com/2010/12/23/mcmc-in-python-custom-stepmethods-and-bounded-depth-spanning-tree-distraction/):

```
class BDSTMetropolis(mc.Metropolis):
    def __init__(self, stochastic):
        mc.Metropolis.__init__(self, stochastic, scale=1., proposal_sd='custom',
            proposal_distribution='custom', verbose=None, tally=False)

    def propose(self):
        T = self.stochastic.value

        T.u_new, T.v_new = T.edges()[0]
        while T.has_edge(T.u_new, T.v_new):
            T.u_new, T.v_new = random.choice(T.base_graph.edges())

        T.path = nx.shortest_path(T, T.u_new, T.v_new)
        i = random.randrange(len(T.path)-1)
        T.u_old, T.v_old = T.path[i], T.path[i+1]

        T.remove_edge(T.u_old, T.v_old)
        T.add_edge(T.u_new, T.v_new)
        self.stochastic.value = T

    def reject(self):
        T = self.stochastic.value
        T.add_edge(T.u_old, T.v_old)
        T.remove_edge(T.u_new, T.v_new)
        self.stochastic.value = T
```

It pretty different than your model, but it should demonstrate all the parts.  Does that give you enough to go on?